# frigidaire upright freezer legs for leveling are missing. They are over $30 for one plactic leg. What can I use instead?

Tags: repair, freezer

They are over $30 for one plastic leg. What can I use instead?

Frididaire upright freezer Model number Electrolux FFFU14F2QWP

Leveling Leg 216396900
Item #446089 | Frigidaire OEM Part #216396900

Thank you very much.

Comment: If this is a new fridge, talk to the store/maker.  If not new, most stores should have levelling legs that might fit.  At worst can use wood/plastic shims for levelling.  Those legs are not that important for the fridge to work, you just want it level.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the Frigidaire OEM Part #216396900 you provided,

I found those on Amazon for $10

[https://www.amazon.com/FRIGIDAIRE-216396900-Frigidaire-Series-Foot-Adjustable/dp/B00ECV6FWK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ECV6FWK)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any stable shim material suitable for the location (if it's a damp area, wood is dubious.)

I have a number of things shimmed with CDs that didn't burn right or AOL CDs (etc.) from the era when one would show up in the mail every week or two. You can purchase plastic shims or wood shims as such. For free you can cut plastic or metal shims from things you would put in the recycling bin.

You can cut chunks of scrap wood.

I have a freezer sitting on 4 bricks mortared to the floor to keep it out of the occasional water and make 4 spots that are level on an un-level floor.

Comment: AOL CDs! Genius.